# How to mix main timeline movieclips with html5 canvas in Adobe Animate CC 2019

Tags: adobe, createjs

I have an existing file with movie clips I need to use. I created a new background within the script editor with createjs and added animation.

The problem is after creating the createjs script it takes over the whole stage and the movie clips from main timeline are no where to be seen, or added to the stage?

I'm assuming the main timeline and html5 canvas are completely separate.

Is there a way to get movie clips from the main timeline to show up on the createjs canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just adding the animate html code to your existing content?

The template that Animate exports expects that it owns the canvas, and sets up its own Ticker, Stage, and update loop.

You can drop a lot of that code, and simply add your `exportRoot` to your existing Stage. It is just the a MovieClip that represents the main timeline in Animate. It can be combined with whatever you want, as long as there is only one Stage (since Stages clear the canvas).

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
stage.addChild(exportRoot); // Animate
stage.addChild(new createjs.Bitmap("path/to/bitmap")); // Custom
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", stage);
```

A workaround is to turn OFF autoClear on the stage that is updated last (the content that is drawn on top), so that it draws the second stage without clearing the first one. I would not recommend this since stages also handle their own mouse events, so there could be some collision there.

Hope this helps. If you can provide a little more information, I can help further.
Cheers,

Comment: Thank you for your response. Made me think about something that helped me figure what I was doing wrong, but found another problem. Kind of how it works, right? I was adding the easeljs cdn in the global include url. Once I deleted the easeljs cdn, the main timeline movie clip shows up behind the createjs canvas. Next Question is, how can I stack the movie clips? Old way was addChildAt(n). Does this still apply?

Comment: again, thank you. You steered me in the right direction. In the end I used stage.addChildAt(shape, n) for the createjs shapes. Stacked them towards the bottom. For the main timeline, I used stage.addChild(this.movieClip) to add the movie clip. I didn't use the var stage = new create.js.Stage('canvas'). That threw an error.

Comment: Sounds good. If you already had a stage, you didn't need that first line in my example.